# What is this function actually returning?

Tags: java

I am beginner in java. In this code i am not able to understand what is this function actually returning. Is it returning the maximum value of the j. If it is returning the maximum value of j, then what is the    return j; doing in the for loop and where is it returning the value of j ?

```
public static int nextIndex(int[] pages, int i) {
    int page = pages[i];

    for (int j = i+1; j < pages.length; j++) {
        if (pages[j] == page) {
            return j;
        }
    }

    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: It's finding the next occurrence of the element at index `i` in the array and returning `MAX_VALUE` if there is no next occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

line by line:

```
int page = pages[i];
```

we set the int variable page equal to the page at the index specified in the function

```
for (int j = i+1; j < pages.length; j++) {
```

we loop through starting from the array index after the i index specified in the function call parameter

```
    if (pages[j] == page) {
        return j;
    }
```

If we find an int value equal to the one we set our page variable to- we return the index (aka- the spot in the array where we find that value)

```
return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

As a default- we return Integer.MAX_VALUE if we are unable to find a value later in the array past the i index that holds the same value as the variable `page`.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it using an analogy. Let's say the integer array "pages" is an array which holds the number of words on the pages. Let's say we have 100 pages so the size of pages array would be 100. Your function takes as argument the pages array and the an integer representing the page number.

nextIndex() is effectively trying to find out the next page whose number of words is equal to the number of words on the page represented by "i"(one of the arguments to your method).

So if you passed i as 20, you're trying to find out the next page after the 20th page which has the same number of words as the 20th page.

If the method doesn't find any page having the same number of words as page i, it returns a default MAX_VALUE(this is where the analogy kinda falls apart, going by my analogy I would've returned -1 indicating that we didn't find any page that matched but that's deviating from the issue here)

Comment: if my pages array contains these elements pages[]={2,3,2,1,5,2,4,5,3,2,5,2} if i keep i=0 means value is 2 and then it will see at which point it has value 2 again. But here may times 2 is occurring so which index of 2 will be returned, the last one or the first index where the 2 comes ?

Comment: The method is returning j when the  pages[j] == page satisfies, so only the first occurence of 2 ie index -> 2 would be returned.

You should try to debug this code and step through each line, that would give you a better understanding of this.